# Stuck in initramfs, need to recover data

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I'm running Ubuntu LTS 10.4 on Virtualbox.  Out of nowhere, I'm unable to boot into my VM and I get stuck in initramfs.

I have another Ubuntu VM that I can mount the virtual HD to.  I just want to copy over my files so I do not lose them.

I attached my virtual HD to /dev/sdb1 and did:

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

Yet when I ls /mnt, my home directory is nowhere to be found.  How can I get access to the original file system?

Comment: Your home directory isn't there, but are the other directories showing up?

Comment: Was your home directory encrypted on that VM?

Comment: A grub directory shows up as well as others.  But nothing in the root filesystem.  The home directory was no encrypted.

Comment: So other directories include lost+found, vmlinuz, memtest etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your home directory is in another partition of the disk ( or even on another disk ). Try first with `fdisk -l`. That should return something similar to:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 145.9 GB, 145999527936
bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
17750 cylinders Units = cylinders of
16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1           7       56196   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3             263         517     2048287+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb4             518       17750   138424072+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5             518         900     3076416   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6             901        1283     3076416   83  Linux
```

Then try mounting every device on the list one by one and check the files on that filesystem until you find your home partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
ls -la /mnt
```

Are the files from your home directory?. If not continue:

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
ls -la /mnt
```

Repeat until bingo.

---

In case of LVM the approach is different.

1. Mount your / partition ( the one you
   identified as the / partition before
   ) on /mnt.
2. Identify what device corresponds to
   what mountpoint ( i.e. sdb3 -> /var,
   sdb4 -> /usr, and so on ).
3. Mount them on the corresponding
   directory of the / you mounted on
   the previous step. ( i.e. if your
   var filesystem is sdb3 do `sudo
   mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/var`, ... ).
4. Finally mount the device where you
   want to copy your home files on
   /mnt/mnt
5. You can then do a `sudo chroot /mnt;
   mount /proc;mount /sys` and begin
   working with your mounted image. (
   Play with lvm as usual ). Mount your
   home filesystem ( it should be
   visible as an lvm volume ), and copy
   the useful data to the /mnt
   directory.
6. Once finished `exit` and you'll be
   back to your server.

Comment: The two partitions at /dev/sdb2 and /dev/sdb5 have types of "Extended" and "Linux LVM" and I can't mount them.

Comment: Will this do the trick for LVM?  sudo apt-get install lvm2    And how do I handle the extended?

Comment: I am unsure of what you are saying.  My primary device is /dev/sda.  The device that I want to recover data from is /dev/sdb.  Running posv shows that /dev/sda5 and /dev/sdb5 have the same volume group of "ubuntu"

Comment: I had to rename the LVM volume, there were duplicates.  Running mount is just hanging though, any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the logical volumes with lvs?. You can try to vgimport the group before attempting to mount

Comment: Ugh, the mount just gets killed, any way I can repair the LVM partition?

Comment: You can try to fsck the partition itself first. Doesn't mount throw any error message?

Comment: Yes, mount said it was "killed".  How can I run fsck?  I tried fsck /dev/sdb but it said the device is in use.  I can run fsck on /dev/sdb1, but it doesn't help.  My data resides wither on /dev/sdb2 or /dev/sdb5.  /dev/sdb5 is my LVM volume

Comment: PHEW ok.  So I had to rename the volume using vgrename as mentioned.  Then I ran fsck against the volume, not the physical device.  And then I was able to mount the volume as described.